# Fitting View into Actionbar

Tags: android, view, android-actionbar, custom-view

I'm working on integrating a custom view into the action bar. Currently I am successfully getting the view to display. However some of the view is appearing off the edge of the action bar boundary.

Is there any way I can set the action bar to adjust it's size to fit the entire contents of the view or is the only solution to make the various components of the view slightly smaller...

many thanks

Comment: @AndyRes Can you post your comment as answer so I can accept it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adjust the height of the ActionBar from the action bar theme style, or you define your custom theme which inherits from the parent theme, and add the "height" attribute. (I don't remember how it was called exactly)